# App name in iTunes connect and name appearing on device should be same?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just searched over google for keeping different names in app bundle and itunes connect, some said we can keep the different name and some said we can't because apple might reject. The below is my concern.

The name I want to display on device is: `myMagZine`

The name I want to display in iTunes is: `MagZine system: myMagZine`

Is it possible?, Whether apple will reject it?

Also, Is version numbering 1.1.0.0 in iTunes connect and 1.1.0 in XCode bundle version allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** It is possible keep the different name on `device` and `iTunes`.

I have an example for this check below :-

iTunes link  [app link](https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/venn-socializing-on-demand/id1156437949?mt=8) , On `iTunes` it's name **Venn - Socializing. On-Demand**.

And on device it's name is **Venn**

Comment: Thank you. How about version number..Also, Is version numbering 1.1.0.0 in iTunes connect and 1.1.0 in XCode bundle version allowed?

Comment: no version numbering must be same Please show your response on my answer@MasterStroke